# Marginal model of longitudinal data with missing data

Tags: panel-data, missing-data, generalized-estimating-equations, marginal-model

I have longitudinal dataset with measurements taken over years.
I plan on modelling a marginal model with a binary outcome (0/1).
My plan was using a GEE for this.

This binary outcome has quite a large amount of drop-out.
However, I know that a GEE has problems with missing data. Especially when that missing data is missing at random (MAR). Yet, I still wanted to go ahead with it since I don't really know any other efficient models for marginal models with a binary outcome.
When I fit the model in R using the "gee" package, this fits but it removes all subjects with NA's. Ironically, only 1 subject has all measurements. The package "geepack" ends up with the same problems.

What would be a good way to go to fit a marginal model without removing all NA's because that isn't an option due to the sparseness of the data. I would be left without any data after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the persons having similar issues.

It was basically a glitch occuring for the library "Gee" in R.
Fitting the models in SAS gave correct results using proc GENMOD.

Comment: You should report the problem to the maintainers of the relevant R packages!